# Removing expired notifications from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

My application uses Firebase Notifications. If Firebase generates two notifications with the same `id`, I display both in my status bar, but I want the older notification to be removed.

My code:

```
  private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(119);

    notificationManager.notify(119 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: You're looking to send a so-called collapsible message, which means that any new message with the same key replaces the previous message with that key. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages

Comment: if you use same id for each notification. than previous notification should be replaced with new one.

Comment: how to add collapse_key parameter please ?

Comment: If you are generating the notification yourself using the code in your question then you can simply call notify again with the same ID and that would update the existing notification or create a new one if it is the first time. Note that if you are sending notifications from the Firebase console that in some cases it would generate notifications without using your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the Notification Id's to remove, just use

```
    notificationManager.cancel(id);
```

If you don't then use

```
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

Comment: What id firebase sets to notification?